# Finite Automata proof with matrix

Tags: math, matrix, proof, finite-automata

NOTE: This is not a homework assignment. The professor mentioned this in class as an optional "fun" activity.

Given an N∗N matrix which is initially colored all white, show that there exists some way to color it all black by selecting indices as the center of a "cross" pattern (based in center, 1 up, 1 left, 1 right, 1 down). All indices in the cross have their colors swapped. For example,

If on a 3*3 board, all the indices are white initially:

- w w w
- w w w
- w w w

and flipping the center indice will make the board, (b = black):

- w b w
- b b b
- w b w

flipping the left corner indice:

- b w w
- w b b
- w b w

The question is if there exist a finite way to make a n*n board, initially coloring all white to be colored all black, by using above flipping mechanism?

Thanks for any insigt.

Comment: [Here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/js/flip.html) is a JS implementation of that game, including a solver which also works on manually entered initial positions, including all black (in that case the goal is to turn all squares white), maybe you can somehow extract the proof from the code.

Comment: [This](http://srabbani.com/lights_out.pdf) paper proves the fact for an even more general question, but uses some linear algebra, if you feel comfortable with this.